# firestore rules compare with firestore data

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following setup in my Cloud Firestore:

```
Collection     Document      Collections  Documents
[USERID]   -   [TESTS]   -   [1]   -      [ANSWERS]
                                          [RESULTS]
                         
                             [2]   -      [ANSWERS]
                                          [RESULTS]

                             [3]   -      [ANSWERS]
                                          [RESULTS]
```

The user can share only the latest test results with the public. In the example above it would be /USERID/TESTS/3/RESULTS.

I store the latest number of tests in /USERID/STATUS.number_tests. In the example below, number_tests = 3. (Every user has one unique userId unter which I store all the data).

How can I limit the access via firestore rules that only latest test result is public? I transfer the userId already, this part works.

Accordiung to the google docuemntation, the resource variable refers to the requested docuemtn and the resource.data is a map of the the fields and values stored in the document.

Accodring to this description i replaced data (which seems to be the docment name) with status (which is the name of my document) and used the dot notation to get access to the (map) data in the status but it doens't work. See my try below:

I also tried the get() because i think I use an entry for another docuemtn to grant access but also this try ended not in a sccess...

1 TRY:

```
match /{userId}/tests/{number}/results {
  allow read: if resource.status.number_answers == number
}
```

2 TRY:

```
match /{userId}/tests/{number}/results {
  allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/$(userId)/resource.status.number_answers == number
}
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions

Can someone help me?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve it myself. The answer is:

```
match /{userId}/test/{cycle}/results {
  allow read: if cycle == string(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/$(userId)/status).data.number)
}
```

Please be aware that I ctried to compare a string with a number, this is why I surrounded the get(...) with the string(get(...))...